# How to analyse each individual vector value in an if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, user-input

I'm trying to use an if statement to analyse the number of user-inputted values greater than or equal to 70. For every value they input greater than (or equal to) 70, I want the variable `totalFirst` to increase by 1. However, I am not sure how to make an if statement analyse each individual value in a vector.

Code so far:

```
totalFirst <- 0

prompt <- "What were your second year module results?(space separated)"
secondYearMark <- as.integer(strsplit(readline(prompt), " ")[[1]])
if (secondYearMark >= 70) totalFirst <- totalFirst + 1
```

Comment: Maybe `totalFirst <- totalFirst + sum(secondYearMark >= 70)`? Or if you only need to calculate once and not increment again later, then just  `totalFirst <- sum(secondYearMark >= 70)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `sum`

```
prompt <- "What were your second year module results?(space separated)"
secondYearMark <- as.integer(strsplit(readline(prompt), " ")[[1]])
totalFirst <- sum(secondYearMark >= 70)
```

Comment: Thank you, and a very simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get user inputs for more than once, you can put `readline` inside a function named `f_getInput` and just call that function:

```
totalFirst <- integer(0)    
prompt <- "What were your second year module results?(space separated)"
f_getInput <- function(prompt) return(as.integer(strsplit(readline(prompt), " ")[[1]]))

totalFirst <- c(totalFirst, f_getInput(prompt))
```

You run the last line for as many times as you want. Finally, you will have all the user inputs in vector `totalFirst`. In order to catch how many times a number `>=70` in entered by the user, just do this:

```
sum(totalFirst >= 70)
```

If, for instance, `totalFirst` contains `25, 33, 85, 64, 71, 70`, by doing this:

```
which(totalFirst >= 70)
```

You know that a number `>=70` is entered in 3th, 5th and 6th input time.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalFirst     <- 0    
prompt         <- "What were your second year module results?(space separated)"
secondYearMark <- as.integer(strsplit(readline(prompt), " ")[[1]])   
totalFirst     <- length(secondYearMark[secondYearMark >=70])
```